# Import a class in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, class, import

I want to import a class that is in App_Code to use it in my aspx pages.

How can I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: What class? How do you intend to use the class? What will the class contain? So many details to provide before this question becomes answerable.

Comment: are you getting any errors? AFAIK you should be able to use the stuff in App_Code just by including the correct namespace of your class with a using statement.

Comment: I defined my own class wich contain some methods and I want to call this methods every time, so I will need to import this class. So I can use his own methods in the aspx page.

Comment: @JohnIdol, I used what you told me the class named (Connexion.vb) in App_Code, and in the aspx page this: <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Connexion.vb" %>. But it's not working.

Comment: Did you call the namespace of your code System.Data.Connexion?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add the namespace you used to your codebehind file or aspx file(if not using code behind).

```
using YourNamespace; //C#
imports YourNamespace //VB
```

or if not using codebehind

```
<%@ Import Namespace="YourNamespace" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your app_code class is in another namespace, add a `using` statement at the top of your code behind.  Example:

```
using MyCustomNamespace;
```

EDIT: if using vb in your code behind:

```
imports MyCustomNamespace
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't add a Namespace clause in your class you won't need to import anything, you can use the class directly from code behind.

If you have a Namespace clause in the class, just add "Imports YourNamespaceName" in the first line of your code behind.