# Class1.cs not appearing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

In my WEB FOLDER I have the file ʻaspx.cs` and the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApplication1.bibliotecario
{
    public partial class adicionar_livros : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\samue\source\repos\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\App_Data\gerenciamentoBiblioteca.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            con.Open();

        }

        protected void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string books_image_name = Class1.GetRandomPassword(10);

            string path = "";
            f1.SaveAs(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "/bibliotecario/imagens_livros/" + f1.FileName.ToString());
            path = "imagens_livros/"+f1.FileName.ToString();
            
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into livros values('"+ titulolivros.Text +"','"+ path.ToString() + "','"+ nomeautor.Text + "','" + isbn.Text + "','" + qtd.Text + "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            msg.Style.Add("display", "block");
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a `.cs` class called `Class1` inside an Asp.net folder, App_Code folder. However, every time I call a `Class1` it is not recognized, there is no option to place it in my code, how do I access it?

[image]

Here is my `Class1.cs`

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication1.App_Code
{

    public class Class1
    {

        public static string GetRandomPassword(int length)
        {
            char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
            string password = string.Empty;
            Random random = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                int x = random.Next(1, chars.Length);
                //For avoiding Repetation of Characters
                if (!password.Contains(chars.GetValue(x).ToString()))
                    password += chars.GetValue(x);
                else
                    i = i - 1;
            }
            return password;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to include your class with `using`. Does this answer your question? [Import a class in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921207/import-a-class-in-asp-net)

Comment: `string books_image_name = App_Code.Class1.GetRandomPassword(10);`

Comment: How can i put this in my code?  `using Class1;` in my `apsx` file?

Comment: When i put `using WebApplication1.App_Code;` it is said that there is no namespace and when i do what VDWWD said to do, it appears that   `App_Code ` does not exist in the current context

Comment: Right click on class1, and make sure in property sheet it is set to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following steps to access the class in the `App_Code` Folder.

First, Right click on the .cs file in the `App_Code` folder and check its properties.

Make sure the "Build Action" is set to "Compile".

Like that:

[image]

Second, please add namespace reference in the code.

```
using WebApplication2.App_Code;
```

Finally, We can call the code successfully.

[image]